# Using Azure Python SDK what is the preferred way to auth a user?

Tags: python, azure, authentication

i'm trying to learn Azure so I thought I create a simple program in order to learn.

I'm having trouble figuring out the best to auth a user. I thought about having Service Principal Credentials but it seems that these would have to be stored on the computer in a file or in the source code. So this does not seem to be ideal since then i need to protect those. I assume the same is true for certificates, that is they need to be saftely stored on my computer. Reading username / password from the user would be an option but that seems to be legacy code. So i'm curious what is the preferred way to auth a user.

In my case this user would have read/list permissions of a secret and the ability to create service principal credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, using Service Principal Credentials/certificates to login to Azure is just for [service to service call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) instead of users .

If you want to login your users and users has permission to call Microsoft Graph APIs to ,generally, you should use 
[Azure AD OAuth 2.0 code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code) flow to login your users.In this flow, users will need to input their username and password to [request an auth code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code) from Azure AD and use this code to [get an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#use-the-authorization-code-to-request-an-access-token) so that they can [access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#use-the-access-token-to-access-the-resource) they requested.

For code details, you can refer to [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-python-webapp-graphapi) directly. In this sample, you will go through the OAuth2.0 flow and call Microsoft Graph API to get current user's basic info(`graphcall` method).

If my understanding is correct, you want your users could manage Azure AD applications, including read/list secrets and resister applications.You can use Microsoft Graph API or [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api-quickstart) to  do that.

If there is anything unclear , pls feel free to let me know .

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I did have a look at Azure managed identities but I do assume those are more focused to cloud based solutions? Atleast so I think since the virtual machine can authenticate itself but I don't see how it could help auth users who are outside the cloud environment.